# Detecting dev env vs. prod env Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `Django` app and **two** Elastic Beanstalks envs: `dev` and `prod`. I want to make some kind of **if statement** in my Django app to **detect which env I am deploying** to (or running locally) and use **different settings accordingly**.

How can I do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use [EB environmental variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console). On each of your EB environments, you could define `ENVIRONMENT` environmental variable in EB with values of either `prod` or `dev`.

Your Django app would check the `ENVIRONMENT` variable and load respective configuration. On your local workstation, the lack of `ENVIRONMENT` would indicate to your app that you are on a local workstation.

Comment: @NGI No problem. Glad could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I usually include a snippet of code like this this at the end of my settings.py:

```
# use or create a local_settings.py file in the same directory as this file to override any production settings - i.e. to turn on debugging and/or change database connection strings.
# do not add the local_settings.py file to the source control
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError as e:
    pass
```

and then only on my local/dev machine have a file called 'local_settings.py' in the same directory where additional config settings can be imported to override the production settings.

If the file exists, it gets imported, and if it is not there, thr try/except just quietly ignores the missing file.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This makes sense, however, I am trying to do this between two different environments AND local. Does that make sense? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: doesn't make any difference - for each environment, put a local_settings.py into the same folder as the settings.py, and that local_settings.py can customize flags/settings for just that env. Don't let the fact that I call it 'local_settings' confuse you, it could be call anything.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but I want the one Django application to be deployed to both environments. So, I need someway to know which env it is running at in my Django app to use different settings accordingly. Does that make sense?